# How do I wait until my data is retrieved from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that I need to wait for the data from Firebase to be retrieved on the method "onDataChange" before ending my main method.

My code is (CalendarDbHelper) :

```
public synchronized ArrayList<Day> listDays()
    {
       final  CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Day day=postSnapShot.getValue(Day.class);
                        listDays.add(day);

                    }
                }
               done.countDown();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

        try {
            done.await(); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listDays;

    }
```

As you can see, I'm already trying to wait with a CountDownLatch, but it doesn't work : it gets stuck.

I need the listDays for the activity "CalendarActivity" where I use it like this :

```
 //Real initialization of the database
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = new CalendarDbHelper(db);
        final List<Day> allDays = mDatabase.listDays();



        //Activating things to click on
        if(allDays.size() > 0){
            calendarRV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            calendarRVAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, allDays, new CalendarAdapter.OnListItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex) {
                    String id = allDays.get(clickedItemIndex).getId();
                    MyCustomAlertDialog(id);
                }
            });
            calendarRV.setAdapter(calendarRVAdapter);
        }else {
            calendarRV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is no product in the database. Start adding now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried Handler?? postdelayed method??

Comment: What do you mean by Handler ? And I never heard about postdelayed method either :c

Comment: You want the method db.addValueEventListener() to be called after some amount of time right??

Comment: Not really, Indeed I want to wait for the method onDataChange() to be done retrieving data, and after that, return listDays, because if it doesn't wait, the listDays that is returned is null

Comment: Now i got your problem. Listen, The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. You need to understand that thing.

Comment: I understand, but I don't see how to solve my problem..

Comment: Try the answer. Just move listDays.add(day); from for() to onDataChange()

Comment: And tell me the result.

Comment: I don't know how to pass that list from that asynchronous method. You can try using SharedPreferences to putList() from onDataChange() and then getList() from the CalenderActivity.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

if this is your "main method",you should put the return data when the **onDataChange** is triggered

Comment: I don't really understand how I'm supposed to do that.. Do you want me to put a "return listDays" inside the onDataChange ?

Comment: @Nouxy is your  "main method" call this function to get the data ???

Comment: if it is,from main,call this method but dont return the data.Keep the view show progress.inside the onDatachange, do the function to update the UI when the data is returned.and if you want to do it just 1 time,clear the datachange listener

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "main method" ? I don't really understand what you're telling me to do

Comment: private OnGetDataDone onDone;
  
  CalendarDbHelper(db,OnGetDataDone onDone){
    this.onDone = onDone;
  }

  public interface OnGetDataDone{
    void onDone(ListDay listday)
  } add this to your CalendarDbHelper and put all the code which update ui in onDone method override in your CalendarActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 public synchronized ArrayList<Day> listDays()
    {
   final  CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
{
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Day day=postSnapShot.getValue(Day.class);
                    listDays.add(day);

                }

             // Do whatever you want to do with your list from here..

            }
           done.countDown();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

    try {
        done.await(); 
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listDays;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work since the Day created inside the "for" loop isn't recognized on the line "listDays.add(day);" that is outside the "for" loop :/

Comment: So the final solution is the updated answer. I was stuck in this situation too, some days ago. I tried this way to work. And everything works perfectly.

Comment: Can I see your full code?? Where you are using that listDays in the code??

Comment: I just uploaded an edit of where I'm using listDays in my code :)